# JPA spring boot, Error accessing field XXXX by reflection for persistent property

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, persistence

worging with JPA in spring boot with an Mysql, intellij as ide.

I'm facing the following error when i try to save the Game entity, but all works fine if a save a Player entity

> "Error accessing field [private java.lang.Integer com.raul.daus.Entities.Player.idPlayer] by reflection for persistent property [com.raul.daus.Entities.Player#idPlayer] : 1;"

below is the Game entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "games")
public class Game {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_game", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer id_game;
    @Column(name = "id_dice", nullable = false)
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Dice.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "id", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Dice> dices = new ArrayList<Dice>();
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Player.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idPlayer")
    private Integer idPlayer;
    @Column(name = "game_result")
    private Integer game_result;
```

Here the Player entity

```
Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "players")
public class Player {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idPlayer", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Integer idPlayer;
    // player name field with 'ANÒNIM' as default
    @Column(name = "player_name", nullable = false)
    @ColumnDefault("'ANÒNIM'")
    private String player_name;
    // Timestamp field with the registered date
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "registerDate", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date registerDate;
    // One to Many relationship with the player games
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Game.class, mappedBy = "idPlayer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Game> games = new ArrayList<>();
    @Column(name = "rate_success", nullable = true, updatable = true)
    private double rateSuccess;
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `idPlayer` field in `Game` is mapped wrongly. It should be:

```java
@Entity
public class Game {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idPlayer")
    private Player idPlayer;

}
```